# How can I match a string containing ä (a with umlaut) using regex in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to match the string "06 März 2021" and I am trying with the regex:

```
r"(\d{1,2})\W(\p{L}{3,20})\W(\d{4})"
```

I tried telling the Regex to use Unicode:

```
RegExp(datePattern, unicode: true);
```

But that doesn't work for ä. It does for some other accented characters though.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging showed me that the ä is treated as 2 characters, an a followed by the umlaut mark.

Because the following 2 strings are not identical (unless stackoverflow messes with the text I type):

```
März
März
```

In the first case the ä is composed from 2 characters, the a and the umlaut. In the 2nd, it's a single character. This can be checked by printing the lengths of the 2 strings (first is 5, second is 4).

After finding this link:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category

I realized that I needed to add the mark class of characters to the regex, so what I ended up with is:

```
r"(\d{1,2})\s([\p{L}\p{M}]{3,20})\s(\d{4})"
```

An alternative would be using canonical decomposition followed by canonical composition on the string using https://pub.dev/packages/unorm_dart

This would turn the 2nd string into the first (use single character for ä instead of 2).

NOTE: This applies to letters with umlauts, but I don't know to what other accented letters it might work for.

**edit:** replaced \W in the regex with \s so it only matches space characters (as suggested by The fourth bird)

Comment: Note that `\W` matches more than a whitespace character.

Comment: @Thefourthbird true, I could use \s. I think \W was left there from when I was trying to find a way to match non space characters. I could have matched the month with \S+ but that would have been too wide of a class of characters, and even something like @#$%^&* would have been matched, which is not what I want :)